# data type error in normalization in python

Tags: pandas, dataframe, type-conversion, normalization

I wanted to normalize the values of my dataframe df using the following code:

```
    # copy the data
df_min_max_scaled = df.copy()

# apply normalization techniques
for column in df_min_max_scaled.columns:
    df_min_max_scaled[column] = (df_min_max_scaled[column] - df_min_max_scaled[column].min()) / (df_min_max_scaled[column].max() - df_min_max_scaled[column].min()) 

# view normalized data
print(df_min_max_scaled)
```

However, I got the error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

So I tried to convert it into float:

```
# copy the data
df_min_max_scaled = df.copy()

# apply normalization techniques
for column in df_min_max_scaled.columns:
    df_min_max_scaled[column] = (df_min_max_scaled[column]) - float(df_min_max_scaled[column].min()) / float((df_min_max_scaled[column].max()) - float(df_min_max_scaled[column].min()) 

# view normalized data
print(df_min_max_scaled)
```

Now I get the error:

```
  Cell In [16], line 9
    print(df_min_max_scaled)
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Which I don't know why because it seems not a syntax error at all.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a syntax error because you have an extra parantheses in the line where you're applying normalization.

But this is unnecessarily complicated – assuming you want all of the columns to be float type, then you can use [astype](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) function to convert all the columns from `string` to `float` before you apply the normalization:

For example:

```
import pandas as pd

## construct df with numeric strings
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':list('1234'),'b':list('4567')})

df_min_max_scaled = df.copy()
df_min_max_scaled = df_min_max_scaled.astype('float')
```

And then your original attempt should run:

```
for column in df_min_max_scaled.columns:
    df_min_max_scaled[column] = (df_min_max_scaled[column] - df_min_max_scaled[column].min()) / (df_min_max_scaled[column].max() - df_min_max_scaled[column].min())
```

Output:

```
>>> df_min_max_scaled
          a         b
0  0.000000  0.000000
1  0.333333  0.333333
2  0.666667  0.666667
3  1.000000  1.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all, before applying any normalization, the type of the entire dataframe must be casted from 'str' to 'float' as far as it contains only numerical values.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html?highlight=astype#pandas.DataFrame.astype

> DataFrame.astype(dtype, copy=True, errors='raise') Cast a pandas
> object to a specified dtype dtype.

```
df_min_max_scaled = df.astype("float")
```

2. Looping over a dataframe rows is not considered a good practice because it's generally slower than vectorized methods that Pandas has.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html?highlight=apply#pandas.DataFrame.apply

> DataFrame.apply(func, axis=0, raw=False, result_type=None, args=(),
> **kwargs) Apply a function along an axis of the DataFrame.

```
df_min_max_scaled = df_min_max_scaled.apply(lambda x: (x - x.min()) / (x.max() - x.min()))
```

3. You can also use rich standartization and normalization tools of scikit-learn library

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#standardization-or-mean-removal-and-variance-scaling

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
df_min_max_scaled = pd.DataFrame(scaler.fit_transform(df_min_max_scaled), columns=df_min_max_scaled.columns)
```